# Can't perform action in background and update progressView in mainThread

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiprogressview

I've this method :

```
func stepThree() {
    operation = "prDatas"
    let entries = self.data.componentsSeparatedByString("|***|")
    total = entries.count
    for entry in entries {
        ++current
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
            self.registerDB(entry)
        })
    }
    status.setProgress(Float(current/total), animated: true)
    finishAll()
}
```

I  want to perform `registerDB` function and update my progressBar when complete.
I tested several way but never succeed

---

**EDIT 1**

Implementing @Russell proposition, work perfectly, but calculating value inside dispatch_async block always result to 0

Is there an issue about operations and multithread ?

method :

```
func stepThree() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        var current = 0
        var total = 0
        self.operation = "prDatas"
        let entries = self.data.componentsSeparatedByString("|***|")
        total = entries.count
        for entry in entries {
            ++current
            self.registerDB(entry)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                print("value of 'current' is :" + String(current))
                print("value of 'total' is :" + String(total))
                print("Result is : " + String(Float(current/total)))
                self.updateV(Float(current/total))
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Console output :

```
value of 'current' is :71
value of 'total' is :1328
Result is : 0.0
```

Comment: Float(current/total) is your problem - the calculation is done first - with integers - and then the result (which is always 0) is converted to a Float.  I had the same issue in my solution, which is why I converted both parameters to floats first

Comment: It's work better, thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will update the status bar immediately - so the job will not have finished.

You need to move the update so that it actually follows the `registerDB` function, and then you have to make the call on the main thread.  Here's an example - using dummy functions instead of your function calls, so that I can ensure it works as expected

```
func stepThree()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        let total = 5 // test data for demo
        for entry in 0...total
        {
            // dummy function - just pause
            sleep(1)
            //self.registerDB(entry)

            // make UI update on main queue
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            {
                self.setProgress(Float(entry)/Float(total))
            })
        }
    })
}

func setProgress(progress : Float)
{
    progressView.progress = progress
    lblProgress.text = String(format: "%0.2f", progress)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. i tested updating from a function called with performSelectorOnMainThread, now breakpoints show me that, function is called at the good time, update value of progressView but not visually...

Comment: I have updated the answer above, wrapping the whole of `stepThree` in a background task, and making main queue calls to update the UI from within it.

Comment: You right, it's work fine ! thanks for that. I encounter a problem regarding the value to progress, i updated my post.

Comment: cool, glad I could help.  Remember - if you like the answer, mark it as correct :-)